# Trace operator in the intersection of Sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose I have a domain $\Omega$ such that the trace operator $T^p:W^{1,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow L^p(\partial \Omega)$. Now suppose I have a function $u\in W^{1,q}(\Omega)\cap W^{1,p}(\Omega)$.

Will we have that $T^p(u)=T^q(u)$?

That is, are the different trace operators equal in the intersection of the Sobolev spaces?

Comment: They agree on $C^\infty (\Omega)$ and this is dense in both sobolev spaces.

Comment: Yeah but whats confusing me is that for $u\in W^{1,p}\cap W^{1,q}$ the sequences that are converging to $u$ in both spaces might be different .

Comment: No, the limit will be the same.

Comment: If we have $\phi_n \rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,p}$ and $\psi_n\rightarrow u$ in $W^{1,q}$ how do you know that $\phi_n|_{L^p(\partial (\Omega))}$ and$\psi_n|_{L^q(\partial(\Omega))}$ converge to the same function?

Comment: If $\Omega$ is bounded (if it isn't you probably can localize, and work with a bounded domain near every boundary point), then $W^{1,p}\subset W^{1,q}$ if $p>q$, so that's one way of seeing that the trace operators will agree.